# PHP use function from included file

Tags: php, include

I uploaded my website on a webserver and now it displays following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getactualeventid()
```

This function is defined in my file `functions.php` and i include it on the top of my `index.php` file by following line:

```
include '.\functions.php';
```

The file `functions.php` is in the same directory as my `index.php`. Are there settings on the server that I need to change?

//EDIT

In the beginning I used `include 'functions.php';` but only a blank page has been loaded, so I tried it with include '.\functions.php'; and then I got at least a clear error message.

I also tried include_once but it doesn't work. I tested the whole stuff on my localhost by using XAMPP where it runs without any problems.

I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `include 'functions.php';`

Comment: My page is blank, when I try it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the syntax should be:

```
include('functions.php');
```

But I would recommend using [`include_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) instead of [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to avoid scenarios where your script might inadvertently attempt to load the same file more than once.

```
include_once('functions.php');
```

But I would also encourage you to use a base path of some sort to prefix the location of the file so you are not constantly juggling relative locations.

For example, in your main config file, you can define a base path like this:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/the/path/to/the/codebase/';
```

Then when you do an `include_once`, the syntax would be:

```
include_once($BASE_PATH . 'functions.php');
```

The benefit of this is no matter how deeply nested your codebase becomes, you will always be anchored to the value of `$BASE_PATH`. And your life will be made tons easier thanks to not having to worry about relative path issues.

Comment: As include is a language construct and not a function, you don't need to include the name of the file that you're including in brackets

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
include('functions.php');
```

Comment: hey john iv been sent message about my ans but i dont understand it. is it about length of my ans or the structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'functions.php';
```

And check your functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can also used `require_once(youFileName.php).`

Answer (score 0):

Use `include 'functions.php'` as your `functions.php` is on the same directory level where your `index.php` is , use `include '../functions.php'` if it is one level before `index.php`. Hope this helps.